# What does "the appearances" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What does "the appearances" mean in this passage?

Does it mean superficial features or arguments that appear to support a particular opinion on a surface level, but have no substantial value upon closer examination?

> But, some one may say, "Let them be taught the grounds of their
> opinions. It does not follow that opinions must be merely parroted
> because they are never heard controverted. Persons who learn geometry
> do not simply commit the theorems to memory, but understand and learn
> likewise the demonstrations; and it would be absurd to say that they
> remain ignorant of the grounds of geometrical truths, because they
> never hear any one deny, and attempt to disprove them." Undoubtedly:
> and such teaching suffices on a subject like mathematics, where there
> is nothing at all to be said on the wrong side of the question. The
> peculiarity of the evidence of mathematical truths is, that all the
> argument is on one side. There are no objections, and no answers to
> objections. But on every subject on which difference of opinion is
> possible, the truth depends on a balance to be struck between two sets
> of conflicting reasons. Even in natural philosophy, there is always
> some other explanation possible of the same facts; some geocentric
> theory instead of heliocentric, some phlogiston instead of oxygen; and
> it has to be shown why that other theory cannot be the true one: and
> until this is shown, and until we know how it is shown, we do not
> understand the grounds of our opinion. But when we turn to subjects
> infinitely more complicated, to morals, religion, politics, social
> relations, and the business of life, three-fourths of the arguments
> for every disputed opinion consist in dispelling **the appearances** which
> favour some opinion different from it.

---J.S. Mill from On Liberty
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/34901/34901-h/34901-h.htm

Comment: I believe that "appearances" refers to arguments apparently sensible, but that may be disproved by some other reasoning, the debater trying to assess that the  argument has just a semblance of validity.

Comment: @Graffito: Your "apparently sensible" implies that the arguments in favour of some (contrary) position ***are in fact flawed***, but Mills intends no such "slur". It may be that any "appearances" being dispelled actually represent the true position - he's just talking in general about how people tend to demolish contrary explanations rather than actively promote the arguments in favour of their own position - regardless of where the truth might actually lie.

Answer (score 1):

The passage is making a point that opinions ought to be based on practical demonstrations in reality rather than just theory:

> Persons who learn geometry do not simply commit the theorems to memory, but understand and learn likewise the demonstrations.

Look at your words in question in their full context:

> three-fourths of the arguments for every disputed opinion consist in dispelling the appearances which favour some opinion different from it.

I understand "the appearances" to be material demonstrations — 'evidence' — that supports an opinion. In other words, to dispute someone's evidence-based opinion you would have to dispel the material evidence supporting it.

It is slightly unusual English; perhaps academic language rather than everyday speech.

Comment: I think you've summarised what Mills is saying in the *earlier* part of the text. But the final sentence (starting at *But when we turn to subjects infinitely more complicated...*) is saying something different. Probably because in those more complicated subjects, we *can't* usually make bulletproof observations to back up our positions - so instead we devote our energies to rubbishing the *opposition's* observations, evidences, and hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a difficult passage for an English learner to be reading, so don't be discouraged!   It uses complex and at times archaic language.

Grafitto's comment above is correct.  "Appearances" here is used in the sense of "false appearances" - evidence that superficially seems to support the truth of a particular idea, but on deeper inspection are revealed to be misleading.

This happens all the time in the the sciences; it is the main way theories are refined.  This is why the author draws a contrast by saying "in natural philosophy, there is always some other explanation possible of the same facts".   The **appearances**, or evidence, that grounded the "phlogiston" theory of his day were seen to lead to wrong conclusions as the phlogiston theory was replaced by the "oxygen" theory - which now represents the current best understanding.

Likewise, he is suggesting that most arguments of "moral philosophy" (spanning what we would today variously call 'ethics', 'epistomology', and 'politics') are concerned with a similar process.  These arguments therefore aim to demonstrate that the "**appearances**" that lead a person to a certain position are false or misleading, so that he  or she will see them in a new light or consider other evidence to reason an opposing viewpoint.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking up the phrase "dispelling the appearances" and stumbled across this sentence. It seems to me like "the appearances" here is used in the same sense as you suggested. What do you think about this?

Comment: "_It was because the Lord possessed, in states of glorification, a Divine perception of all things which were taking place,-in heaven, on earth, and in His own mind and body,-that He was able to meet and subjugate the bells, gradually dissipating their fallacies, **dispelling the appearances** of truth by which they deceive men ..._" [link](https://newchristianbiblestudy.org/bundles/ncbsw/on-deck/english/new-church-life/1922_HTML.htm)

Comment: Exactly, this is a similar usage.

Comment: So it's not exactly the same but just similar?

Comment: It's exactly the same meaning and sense of the word 'appearances'.   ("Similar" use in that the exact phrase is different!)

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

In its entry for [***appearance***](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/appearance_n?tab=meaning_and_use#412481), the full Oxford English dictionary has this definition 12c...

> **save the appearances** Originally Astronomy
> *[compare Middle French, French **sauver les apparences** (c1400 in astronomy; c1377 in Middle French in more general use in the sense **‘(of a hypothesis) to account for observed facts’),** Italian **salvar le apparenze**; compare also earlier to **salve the appearances** (see **salve** v.2 1) and to solve the appearances (**solve** v. 3b) and discussion at those entries] : **said of a hypothesis which satisfactorily explains the observed facts.** See also **salve** v.2 1. Cf. **to save the phenomena** at **phenomenon** n. Phrases.*

Their earliest citation is 1667 (in Milton's *Paradise Lost*), and I initially thought it was at least "dated", if not archaic. So I was somewhat surprised to see this for their most recent citation...

> **1981** *His single professional aim is to perceive order in the physical world, not merely to save the appearances but to discover an ordered reality.*
> Country Life 26 February 528/3

Mills is talking about demolishing rather than "saving" the appearances, but essentially, *dispelling the appearances which favour some opinion different from it* means *brushing aside any justifications for contrary opinions* (arguing ***against opposing opinions***, rather than ***for one's own position***).

Comment: Thank you. Let me check my understanding. So in your interpretation, "appearances" means "observed facts," and those facts may turn out to be false or true. And what Mill is pointing out here is that people are often keen on arguing against contrary opinions, but not so much on promoting their own opinions. Is my understanding correct?  
Your interpretation also seems to align pretty well with Astralbee's, doesn't it?

Comment: No. ***Appearances*** refers to ***a hypothesis which satisfactorily explains** the observed facts*, as the definition says.

Comment: ...Don't forget Mills is only making his claim (about arguing *against* opposing opinions, rather than *for* one's own position) in the specific context of "more complicated subjects" (morals, religion, politics,...) where it's actually quite difficult to produce "evidence" to back up one's position. And I think he's implying that precisely *because*  that's difficult in those subject areas it's easier to simply rubbish your opponents "evidence", rather than produce your own.

Comment: Bear in mind very few native Anglophones would really be able to understand the text right down to the level of *What exactly does the word "appearances" mean here?* I'd have no chance if I didn't have free access to the full OED, and I certainly won't bother to remember it. The text might be useful to someone studying the history of philosophy, but it's not really relevant to "learning English". Hardly anyone would be able to understand you if you ended up learning to write like Mills!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Isn't "a hypothesis which satisfactorily explains the observed facts" the definition of "save the appearances", rather than "the appearances" itself? That OED definition is about "save the appearances".

Comment: Also, according to the following definition, "save the appearances" refers to a scientific method (which I think includes hypotheses that follow this method), and "the appearances" seems to refer to "observable patterns and phenomena".


_>"The Saving the Appearances approach is a method of interpreting and understanding physical phenomena in terms of observable patterns and phenomena, rather than attempting to explain them in terms of underlying causal mechanisms. "_
[link](https://www.astronomyclub.xyz/uniform-circular/plato-and-saving-the-appearances.html)

Comment: That's not how I read it. note that the definition says "saving the appearances" is *said of a hypothesis which satisfactorily explains the observed facts*. The way I see it, Mills is deliberately and specifically "riffing" off that usage with ***dispelling** the appearances* as opposed to ***saving** the appearances*.

Comment: But this is barely about English in its normal sense any more. You've got the full OED definition there, for what use you can make of it. Also bear in mind that in "normal" English, there's no meaningful connection between ***save, solve,*** and ***salve***, and I'm sure the OED's entry for ***to save the phenomena*** would muddy the waters even further.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now I understand that "dispelling the appearances" is a riff off of "saving the appearances", but what I'm confused about is that you previously said _"**Appearances** refers to a hypothesis which satisfactorily explains the observed facts"_, but now you said _"**"saving the appearances"** is said of a hypothesis which satisfactorily explains the observed facts"_.  Which phrase is the definition actually describing?

Comment: I can't help you with that question. The usages here don't correspond to anything that I know about how English works - that's why I said this is barely about English anyway. All I can be pretty certain of is that Mills probably wouldn't have used the words ***dispelling** the appearances* if it weren't for the pre-existing ***saving** the appearances* (which expression he was obviously *far* more familiar with than me! :)

Comment: I see. I've never seen the expression "saving the appearances" before but interpreting "dispelling the appearances" as a riff off of it, is actually interesting. Thank you for your time and valuable insights.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Well, like I said, I myself will make no effort to remember the usage ***saving the appearances*** or any of the associated forms mentioned in the OED definition. It seems to be an oddball usage that somehow "migrated" from astronomy to philosophy. I'm interested in English in general, but this one doesn't seem relevant to anything else, so I'm only engaging with it temporarily because *you* want to know something. It's not relevant to learning English, though, so I'll probably vote to close it unless someone else can find a way to make it more "On Topic".

Comment: No.  "save the appearances" is an idiom which is not used in the passage here, this is completely wrong.

Comment: @BadZen: The collocation ***dispelling the appearances*** appears dozens of times in Google Books, but so far as I can see, *every single one* is either Mills' original, or others quoting or alluding to it (as [this one,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22alternative+opinions+and+dispelling+the+appearances%22) with the words in "scare quotes"). Which easily convinces me that Mills' use is *predicated* on the pre-existing idiom (he's riffing off it, and would never have written what he did if that weren't the case). But if you want to think different, I can't stop you, obviously.

Comment: What are you even talking about?  Your copypasta quotas Milton above, and gives to roots of the phrase dating to the 15th century.   I don't know what corpora you are using, but I see thousands of examples of consistent usage in COHA and contemporary corpora.  I assure you they were not all quoting a neologism or idiosyncrasy of Mills.   More importantly however, as usual you are merely confusing learners by not directly and simply answering what is asked.  That is the main reason your answer is bad.

Comment: I'm intrigued. Show me a few of your "thousands" of written instances of "dispelling the appearances" that aren't obviously related to Mills' use. Note that although Google Books isn't exactly "curated", it's *far* bigger than any other corpus.